# input/output error during write on /dev/sda during Ubuntu installation

Tags: 18.04, grub2, software-installation, 19.04

I know, there is the same question but it hasn't been resolved, and the solution there didn't work for me. 
Here is my issue in detail:

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 using a bootable pen drive. I used YUMI to do this.
There will be a single os on the disk(no multiboot)

(I also tried with Ubuntu 18.04.2, and got the same error)

```
Error: input/output error during write on /dev/sda during Ubuntu installation
```

I get this dialogue box after I select the "format disk and install Ubuntu" option. And once this box appears, it won't go so I have to long press the power button.

I also tried installing it with - "Try Ubuntu and then install"
Here the OS is installed successfully but once it restarts, it will give another error:

```
error: failure reading sector 0xcf1ecf from hd0
error: you need to load the kernel first 
Press any key to continue
```

On key press, it gives the GNU GRUB v2.02 window.
When I select Advanced option for ubuntu-> Ubuntu with Linux 5.0.0-13-generic it gives the error:

```
error: attempt to read-write outside disk hd0
```

I am a newbie to Linux, so it would be helpful to explain even basic steps in details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have the typical NTFS lock issue. let's try to reinstall it.

run "Cmd" or "Powershell" as an Administrator and type in it :

```
powercfg -h off
```

then try again. also for best results make sure you make your LiveUSB ad GPT/UEFI :

to do this use [rufus](https://rufus.ie/) not yumi.

you can then select GPT & UEFI in the drop down menus.

also when you boot to the LiveUSB if you have several choices for the USB, choose the one that says "UEFI" or "EFI"

it'll be on rails from there :) !

Comment: So in the partition scheme I should use GPT instead of MBR? Doing this changes the Target system as UEFI(non CSM)

Comment: If you have a preinstalled Windows 8 or newer then it is in UEFI mode. Ubuntu should boot and install in the same mode. That way Grub will be correctly installed in the EFI partition.

Comment: I tried the above method, didn't work. Gave me an error saying select MBR instead of GPT. Also only 1 hard disk is connected so no dual boot @GabrielaGarcia . Also: My computer is very old. Can this be the reason to the problem?

Comment: That means you're booting in lagacy mode.

Comment: Should I or should I not boot in legacy mode?

Comment: I know how to select booting from usb, but there is no UEFI support in my motherboard.

Comment: oh ok. then you won't have that choice and that's for the best

Comment: Ya. Thanks anyways for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your installation disk is encrypted or avoiding the files to be copied into your folder. At least in my case, I was trying to install Ubuntu using VMWare Workstation Pro on my Job profile which encrypts part of my disk. I change the location path when configuring your VM and point to an external disk that I have controlled.