# Can't install Ubuntu 18.04, error writing on /dev/sda

Tags: system-installation

Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB drive. I select to erase everything on my hard drive and install Ubuntu (no OS on the hard drive detected). However a few seconds after I proceed I get an error which says "error writing on /dev/sda".
I am still a newbie to Linux, even though I have some little experience. How to fix this problem?

EDIT: Everything with the ISO seems fine. I ran `smartctl -x /dev/sda` and this is what I got:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
No failed Attributes found.
```

Also `gnome-disks` says that "disk is likely to fail soon".

Comment: How are you installing your ubuntu....through the grub option to intsall or after you have live booted.

Comment: How you are making the USB bootable? In what OS you are making this bootable? Do you have the correct format? Give us more background information so that we can understand what is the problem.

Comment: Also check this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150031/input-output-error-during-write-on-dev-sda-during-ubuntu-installation

Comment: I tried installing both from GRUB and liveboot, but I get the same error. I made the USB bootable on Windows 10 using Rufus on another laptop. Also before that I tried installing Arch Linux and I was working with partitions so I am afraid it might have something to do with it

Comment: Did you verify the ISO download?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 Did you verify your write to your install media? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  Given the errors on /dev/sda did you verify the health of your media (`smartctl`, `gnome-disks` or check SMART data from your hdd/ssd) and more detail may help (sda? is the drive, not a partition on the drive?? thus it sounds more like hardware fault or faulty install media (invalid ISO or write of ISO))

Comment: Looks like the ISO is fine. I ran smartctl and gnome-disks and according to both my drive is expected to fail. Also I have had this laptop for just nearly one year

Comment: Well, looks like you have found your answer. Well done!

Comment: Sounds like your HDD may be defective. Lets look a little closer for details. Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app `SMART Data` window... this may take 2 screenshots to get all of the information. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. (Read my story below if you like.)

This basically says that the hard drive is broken:

> SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
>   Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
>   No failed Attributes found.

You really should only use hdds that are in a good condition. So sudo `smartctl -x /dev/sda` should return the line `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`. Only then you should use it.

You can test your hard drive with a similar tool on another PC to be sure (same for providing more of the smartctl output), but I would suggest you try another (new) hard drive instead. Installation should work fine then.

In my case, the disk was simply broken. Reading out the S.M.A.R.T values on a different PC showed some red flags. There must've been some physical damage, probably from falling down while in use. The install would always fail after some minutes. Later I found out that approximately sectors corresponding to 3 GB where working, but some sectors later where broken. The installation would simply not continue.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing usb port of my laptop did the trick.