# Can't dual boot my Windows with Ubuntu, Input/Output error during write on /dev/sda

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I am trying to dual boot my system, but I'm facing this error `Input/Output error during write on /dev/sda` at the step when I need to configure the partitions. I have tried many desktop environments thinking the error maybe with the ISO or anything but every one of that failed with this error. I checked out [Can't install Ubuntu 18.04, error writing on /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191979/cant-install-ubuntu-18-04-error-writing-on-dev-sda) this as well, but I couldn't found desired solution.

I have also checked my hard disks health. I have attached a screenshot of hard disk checkup using Hard Disk Sentinel.

[image: screenshot here]

Is there an issue with the hard disk health or there is any other problem?

Here is a screenshot of my drive properties, and it certainly isn't dynamic (currently there isn't any unpartitioned space).

[image: screenshot]

Here is the output of `sudo fdisk -l -u` (while I was in the live environment), I got an error like this `The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.`

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.33 GiB, 2498256896 bytes, 4879408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 155.63 MiB, 163188736 bytes, 318728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 61.89 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 248.76 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 81.26 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 43.63 MiB, 45748224 bytes, 89352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5FFA138B-665C-4351-A262-D14538238857

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616  208671372  208431757  99.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  208672768  209715199    1042432   509M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  209717248 1743806463 1534089216 731.5G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.59 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4D93C4BE-8A6E-4BB5-8609-37256EB1685D

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 30595038 30592991 14.6G Microsoft basic data
```

Here is the output of sudo parted -l

```
Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sda
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? Ignore                                               
Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will
be used.
OK/Cancel? ok                                                             
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   123MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      123MB   107GB  107GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      107GB   107GB  534MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 5      107GB   893GB  785GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: SanDisk Cruzer Blade (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                 Flags
 1      1049kB  15.7GB  15.7GB  fat32        Main Data Partition  msftdata
```

Here is some of the distros I have tried to install

1. Xubuntu 22.04
2. Linux mint 20.2 Uma
3. Ubuntu 22.04

Here is the methods I use

1. First create an installation media with the iso using rufus/ balena etcher
2. make writable parttion using create and format hard disk partition from windows
3. Installing the image by booting into the live media

In the step where we need to configure the root drive, swap partition manually I am getting the error that it could not create the partition and following that I was getting `error writing on /dev/sda`.

**Edit 2**: Since then I have tried different things mentioned in the answers but none of them worked, here is what I have tried the following. (*Earlier I mentioned different flavors of ubuntu, which I am removing to make it platform specific.*)

1. Tried fix the gpt by following the suggestions (didn't work)
2. Tried installing windows afresh and then tried to install Ubuntu 22.04. Below is the screenshot of the partitions I have before install [image: partition menu]
3. To my surprise the boot menu didn't recognize that I am running windows [image: boot menu1], and I selected something else and just added the as root directory and continue and hit the dead end with [image: boot menu2] just the same error I was facing earlier. Sorry for the low end pictures as I couldn't screenshot while the installer is on.
   ***Note** : I have followed the official tutorial for installing Ubuntu*

Comment: I suggest that you follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). Step 6 links to a quality blog post with additional details about setting up dual boot configurations. However in general, you really only need to ensure that before you try to install Ubuntu, that you have enough unpartitioned free space and that you boot the Ubuntu USB as UEFI if Windows is installed as a UEFI OS (or legacy if Windows is not UEFI for some reason)

Comment: It isnt the first time I am trying to dual boot my system, I am quite familiar with the tutorials, FYI I have enough unpartitioned space, I have installed windows as UEFI and trying to boot in UEFI as well so no problem in that as well.

Comment: Can you post the output of this commands? sudo fdisk -lu sudo parted -l

Comment: The problem may be with Windows partitioning. It may have dynamic partitions, etc. Please add a screenshot of your partitions from Windows. With a standard disk properties tool.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have updated the question with a screenshot, please check that out.

Comment: @trokyam I have updated the question with the commands output, please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: There is a procedure to repair a GPT table here. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html I’ve not done this myself so proceed at your own risk and backup any data you cannot afford to lose before starting.

Comment: Quick version of PonJar's link. More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802

Comment: *"FYI I have enough unpartitioned space"* - Where is it? In your screenshot of Windows' partition tool and your output of `parted` there is not any unpartitioned free space.

Comment: @Nmath it's not there as I haven't created, but later I tried and it's the same. The main culprit here is `Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sda`. Can you tell a workaround for this error? Why this error is happening, what could be the possible way to solve this? Again I know how to do dual boot but this error seems new and never happened before, last time I had manjaro gnome installed and tried to remove that but faced grub error and later I tried to install windows fresh, since then I couldn't install any version of Linux.

Comment: @Nmath please check out the updated question, see whether I have skipped the mentioned steps.

Comment: We really can't troubleshoot when you're providing info about Xubuntu, and Mint, and other distros and versions. It blurs the lines of your problem and makes all details and fact-finding ambiguous . Linux Mint is [off topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), so if you want help on AU, you should be using Ubuntu. To avoid ambiguity and variability, *the details in your question should come from only one flavour and version of Ubuntu*.  I suggest that you start over from the beginning, including creating new installation media--use the official tutorial as I suggested in my earlier comment.

Comment: You do not need to create partitions manually and in the majority of cases you should not. If you have met all prerequisites, then the Ubuntu installation will detect your Windows installation and provide you with a guided "Install Alongside Windows option" on the same screen as the option to "Erase Disk". You must have: 1) valid installation media that passes integrity checks 100% 2) the USB boot mode must match the existing Windows' installation (either UEFI or Legacy); and 3) an undamaged/uncorrupted, unlocked disk, with enough unpartitioned free space (25GB+) for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Nmath I have tried a fresh install of Ubuntu following official guidelines . Verified the ISO, Created live media / bootable media (I have kept it GPT as windows is in that format), Created unpartitioned space of 100 GB, tried to install Ubuntu 22.04 and ended up with similar condition as I was facing earlier. Also I have updated my question accordingly. Not to mention my bios is in UEFI so as the windows. Even I have tried out different USB stick to check whether its silly issue with the stick only but facing same error. Can you figure out now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137988/discussion-between-akash-and-nmath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your diskspace is allocated.
Boot into the Live environment and delete a NTFS partition because there is no unallocated space. Do that with GParted. Or you can do that in Windows.
Or you can change the format from NTFS to EXT4.
Or you can unallocate space ( delete a partition ) in Windows. 
Maybe you can choose 'other options' during the installation procedure to delete a partition and create the EXT4 partition for your installation, although I never tried that before, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I have tried shrinking a partition in windows and then I would eventually create root for that partition but due to some reason this leads to `Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sda` even I tried to erase everything and do a fresh install and it leads me to this error again and then the whole setup crashes. I can only easily install windows, it happened last time when I tried to delete manjaro gnome from my system, but ended up re installing windows again (did some grub error), after that I tried xubuntu,Ubuntu,Linux mint, each of them ended up with the same error.

Comment: WIth the added information I can see that you have 16 bad sectors and 664 weak sectors. Your disk health is at 43 %. Modern disk have an overcapacity to put into action when there are some bad sectors, so they can use the hidden overcapacity ones. With a disk health of 43 % you should really think about replacing your disk and secure/backup your important documents, photos, videos, music and that kind of stuff. I think on a healthy disk you won't run into this problem. That said, or rather written, what is the health of the usb-stick you are using. Can you try another one?

Comment: The second time I have tried, it was a different USB stick so I suppose that USB stick may not be in fault rather the disk is acting suspiciously and I also think there won't be any issue if I try this in a new disk. Again do Linux usually have these problems while getting installed into a nearly dead disk or it is general for any OS? As I tried to install windows 8.1/windows 10 it didn't throw any error while getting installed.

Comment: If the disk cannot reallocate the dead or dying sectors this probably will happen installing almost any Operating System. Had this also on Mac with a 55 % disk and encountered problems with Windows ( back in the days from 3.0 to 7 ). I guess they have altered the instalation process, but you will get problems later. Replacing the disk is your best and most secure option.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess this was the reason I cannot install Ubuntu, you can modify your answer if necessary, I am accepting your last comment as the answer hence marking your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

BEFORE FOLLOW THIS TAKE A BACKUP! You can loose everything on disk.

Btw, you have a corrupted gpt table. Follow this.

https://docs.openstack.org/swift/queens/ops_runbook/procedures.html

```
sudo apt install gdisk
gdisk /dev/sda
```

On the command prompt inside gdisk type:

r (recovery and transformation options)

d (use main GPT header) ,

v (verify disk)

w (write table to disk and exit)

Y when prompted in order to confirm actions.

Comment: The link you have shared had the tutorial for fixing corrupt backup gpt table, in my case it was primary gpt table. I hope you have considered that and posted the answer.

Comment: What? You have the exact issue of the link. Read it again.

Comment: In the provided link I can see `Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will
be used.` but I have this `Error:The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).